# Todo app review and checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, sass, materialize

I was just wondering If I could get some thoughts and feedback on my todo app to see where I could improve. Also, one current issue I'm having the is with the checkbox.

I'm using the materialize framework to help create the UI but I can't get the materialized styled checkbox to function properly. My way around that was to place the standard checkbox over the materialized styled one with the help of positioning and `Z-index`, with the `opacity` at `0`.

So the checkbox can still function while the materialized checkbox displays. The issue with that is that If I input to many characters for the task the standard checkbox moves.

[Link to todo-app](https://codepen.io/edwardspresume/pen/GyBmLX)`()`

Comment: At this point it seems like the checkboxes position is random. https://i.imgur.com/Q4N1PhV.png Usual practice is to hide the checkbox completely and add an onclick event to the element that mimics it. In the onclick handler 1) change the click status of the checkbox 2) do whatever else you need to.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! It's not random the position moves base on the amount have characters inputted (sorry just clarified that in the original post) Hmm that would work but the materialized checkbox is some funky stuff lol. I going to ticker around and try to bind the two checkboxes tho. Thank you for the tip!